# factor MSZoning has new levels NA(new factor in data but not in linear regression model)

Tags: r, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to use some dataset from kaggle for house price prediction.

This is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
dataset=read.csv('train(1).csv')
dataset_test=read.csv('test(1).csv')

dataset_test$SalePrice<-0

#test
summary(comb$MSZoning)


#testend


comb=rbind(dataset,dataset_test)
#str(dataset)
#test
#colSums(is.na(comb))
#testend
#colnames(comb)[colSums(is.na(comb)) > 0]
sub_int_cols=Filter(is.integer, comb)
sub_factor_cols=Filter(is.factor, comb)

names_na_fac_col=colnames(sub_factor_cols)[colSums(is.na(sub_factor_cols)) > 0]
names_na_int_col=colnames(sub_int_cols)[colSums(is.na(sub_int_cols)) > 0]

#dataset[]=lapply(dataset, function(x){if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x})

for(i in 1:length(names_na_fac_col)){
  comb[[names_na_fac_col[i]]]=as.character(comb[[names_na_fac_col[i]]])
}
sub_chr_cols=Filter(is.character,comb)
names_chr_col=colnames(sub_chr_cols)

for(i in 1:length(names_chr_col)){
  comb[[names_chr_col[i]]]=ifelse(is.na(comb[[names_chr_col[i]]]),
                                        "NA",
                                        comb[[names_chr_col[i]]])
}

for(i in 1:length(names_chr_col)){
  comb[[names_chr_col[i]]]=as.factor(comb[[names_chr_col[i]]])
}
#correct
for(i in 1:length(names_na_int_col)){
  comb[[names_na_int_col[i]]]=ifelse(is.na(comb[[names_na_int_col[i]]]),
                                     0,
                                     comb[[names_na_int_col[i]]])
}

# for(i in 1:length(names_na_fac_col)){
#   print(summary(comb[[names_na_fac_col[i]]]))
# }

library('binst')
#dataset$YearBuilt=create_bins(dataset$YearBuilt,
#                             seq(min(dataset$YearBuilt),max(dataset$YearBuilt),10))

comb$YearRemodAdd=create_bins(comb$YearRemodAdd,
                                 seq(min(comb$YearRemodAdd),max(comb$YearRemodAdd),10))

#summary(comb$YearRemodAdd)

comb$YrSold=create_bins(comb$GarageYrBlt,
                                c(1910,1920,1930,1940,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,2000,2010))



data_pp=subset(comb, Id %in% seq(1,1460,1))
data_test_pp=subset(comb, Id %in% seq(1461,2919,1))
data_pp=data_pp[,-1]
#----------------------------------
regressor=lm(SalePrice~.,data = data_pp)
summary(regressor)

data_test_pp1=data_test_pp[,-1]
res=predict(regressor,newdata = data_test_pp1)
```

There are 81 columns in dataset which are used to train a linear regression model. The thing is on kaggle datasets came in 2 pieces(train and test namely). Both of them some NA's which are taken care of in preprocessing(As shown in above code). The training and test sets are initially combined. Then all factor columns are converted into character columns. Then missing values in those columns are filled with "NA" value. Then finally those columns are converted again into factor columns. After that train and test sets are divided(As they were in given files, no split function is used). When I try to run the predict function i get error 'factor xyz has new levels NA' The problem here is for example column 'MSZoning' has no NA factors in training dataset, but some rows in test set have 'MSZoning' as factor NA. Thus the model is not trained to predict a resulting value whose 'MSZoning' is NA(the model is not trained to see MSZoning as NA). 
I simply cant remove these rows from test set as the competition needs all rows from test set. Is there a way to tackle this issue and get predictions for all rows in test set without dropping any rows or columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have NA's, you have some cells that have the *text* "NA" in them.

It's this chunk that's introducing "NA" (*not* NA's):

```
for(i in 1:length(names_chr_col)){
  comb[[names_chr_col[i]]]=ifelse(is.na(comb[[names_chr_col[i]]]),
                                        "NA",
                                        comb[[names_chr_col[i]]])
}
```

The problem is that you're adding a new level called "NA" to each factor with missing values. However, since you don't have a factor called "NA" in your training data, when it shows up in your test data your model doesn't know what to do about it. (To help you with the intuition about why unseen categories are a problem: Imagine you're a vet that only knows about cats and dogs. If someone brings you an animal and is like "here's a pig!" you won't know what to do with it.)

As a first pass, I'd recommend replacing NA's with the most common value for that factor rather than creating a new level of your factor.

I've written [a notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/rtatman/replicating-so-error/) that walks through what's going wrong and shows how to replace values.